# Gettin a target pattern contains no '%' from not modified makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

,I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113138/target-pattern-contains-no-makefile) question, but it didn't help me. I have this Makefile on linux:

```
appname := hesaff

PARALLELOPENCV=$(HOME)/ParallelOpenCV/install_gcc
INCLUDE=$(PARALLELOPENCV)/include
OPENCVLIB=$(PARALLELOPENCV)/lib

CCDIR=/home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/Descriptors/hesaff

INTEL_INSPECTOR=-g -O0 -qopenmp-link dynamic -qopenmp
INTEL_OPT=-O3 -simd -xCORE-AVX2 -parallel -qopenmp -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -fma -align -finline-functions
#better not include -ipo for advisor and -qopt-report
#-ipo -fargument-noalias -ansi-alias -no-prec-div -fp-model fast=2 -fma -align -finline-functions

INTEL_PROFILE=-g -qopt-report=5 -Bdynamic -shared-intel -debug inline-debug-info -qopenmp-link dynamic -parallel-source-info=2 -ldl

CXX := icpc
CXXFLAGS := -I/opt/intel/advisor_2017.1.1.486553/include/ -I$(CCDIR) -I$(INCLUDE) $(INTEL_PROFILE) $(INTEL_OPT) -std=c++11


LDFLAGS= -L$(OPENCVLIB) $(INTEL_PROFILE) $(INTEL_OPT)
LDLIBS= -ltbb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs

srcfiles := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp")
headerfiles := $(shell find . -name "*.hpp")
srcfiles := $(srcfiles) $(shell find $(CCDIR) -name "*.cpp" ! -name "hesaff.cpp")
headerfiles := $(headerfiles) $(shell find $(CCDIR) -name "*.hpp")

objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(srcfiles)))

VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(srcfiles)))

all: $(srcfiles) $(appname)

$(appname): $(objects)
    $(CXX) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

depend: .depend

.depend: $(srcfiles) $(headerfiles)
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXDISALBE) -MM $^>>./.depend;

clean:
    rm -f $(appname) $(objects)

dist-clean: clean
    rm -f *~ .depend

include .depend
```

I get this error:

```
makefile:32: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

The weirdest thing is that I don't remember to changed it at all and suddendly it started to give this error, why?

Comment: There is no reason for `$(srcfiles)` to be a prerequisite of `all`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem by myself: Intel Advisor created a new directory called `advixe` which created the error. Moving it solved the problem.

Comment: That still sounds like a bug in the makefile.